# Problem sending a Blob via ajax in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an app made in javascript that exports a custom 3d model in a blob and then convert it to .STL, what I want to do is send an ajax request to functions.php in which the blob is received, saved on the server and then added to a product in Woocommerce, but whenever I try to send the blob I get an error 400  of part of the admin-ajax.php file, if I make the request without the blob the product is created successfully, if there is a way to send the file to the server better than I'm trying I hope someone can explain me

javascript code:

```
function addToTheCart(blob) {
  var data = new FormData();
    data.append('action', 'jf_ajax_Fproduct');
    data.append('file', blob);

    $.ajax({
        url :  jf_vars.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
          window.location.href = "https://test.samplepage.com/?add-to-cart=" + data.toString();
        },    
        error: function() {
          alert("Error!");
        }
    });
}
```

PHP code:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jf_add_f_to_cart');

function jf_add_f_to_cart()
{
    wp_register_script('jf_f_script', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/ajax-funko.0.1.5.js', array('jquery'), '1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jf_f_script');

    wp_localize_script('jf_f_script', 'jf_vars', ['ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')]);
}


add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_jf_ajax_Fproduct', 'jf_add_new_f');
add_action('wp_ajax_jf_ajax_Fproduct', 'jf_add_new_f');


function jf_add_new_f()
{
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( array( 'post_title' => 'producto file' . $i,
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            )
        );
        
    if(isset($_FILES['file']) and !$_FILES['file']['error']){

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "assets/" . "newFile.STL");
}
    
    // Then we use the product ID to set all the posts meta
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type' ); // set product is simple/variable/grouped
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'yes' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', '' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', '' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_purchase_note', '' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', 'no' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', '11' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_length', '11' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_width', '11' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_height', '11' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', 'SKU11' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', array() );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', '' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', '' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', '20' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sold_individually', '' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_manage_stock', 'yes' );
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_downloadable_files' , $temp_name);
        wc_update_product_stock($post_id, 1, 'set');
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_backorders', 'no' );
        
        
    echo $post_id;
    die();
}
```